# What happens if you score more than 99 points in volleyball?

Tags: here-comes-niko

Some stages in *Here Comes Niko!* have a volleyball minigame with a 2 digit score counter on the side. What happens if you get a score above 99?

[image: Volley with high score of 4]

Comment: +1. Like Obama said, these are the questions that keep me up at night.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The score counter for volleyball maxes out at 99.

[image: 99 points in Volley]

Interestingly though, your save file tracks your volleyball high scores past the 100 mark, even if it isn't shown in-game.

[image: Save file with "volleyHighScore":104]